# Forked repository - Resolving the same merge conflicts every time I sync with upstream

Tags: git, github, merge-conflict-resolution, git-fork

I have forked a repository, but I'd like to keep it in sync with the upstream repository often. I have swapped some modules with my own implementation, so that means that every time I want to sync with the upstream repository, I keep getting the same merge conflicts over and over again.

My question is: Is there a way to tell Git to use my own implementation for these case, rather than marking it as merge conflict? Is there something that I can automatize here, so I don't run into the same issues over and over again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `rerere` machinery ("reuse recorded resolutions"):

```
git config rerere.enabled true
```

If the exact same conflict turns up again that has been resolved (and commited!) earlier, its resolution is applied again. By default, you still have to confirm the resolution, but it does the grunt work for you.

`rerere` works only for content conflicts, not for add/modified or delete/modified conflicts.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was helpful!