# How to create a new repository with very few content from old repository?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a monolithic rails application which is used for both read and write. Now I want to separate out the read from write, so I can deploy only the read part separately.

I have a git repo which contains rails app. Now i want to extract out very few routes, controllers and models from the original repo and create a new repo. I would like to deploy the new repo as a separate app similar to microservice. But the problem is how to keep the new repo models in sync with the old repo?

If I update the models in the old repo it should be updated in new repo. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to make a [fork](https://help.github.com/en/articles/fork-a-repo) of the repository. Allows you to make a copy of the repo, make changes, and merge in the upstream changes as needed while respecting the differences between your repositories

Comment: thanks for suggestion. What happens if I delete some folders in new repo and someone commits on the same folder? Will that folder appear in my new repo?

Comment: i forked the repo, deleted the folders and did a commit. But when i do `git pull upstream master` i get conflicts saying that folder is there in original repo. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Yes. Run `git status` for list of conflicted files. Then do `git rm <filename>` on each and commit when finished (I like to mention that it's a merge conflict commit in the message). I think it would also work to delete them manually but I'm not positive they won't come back. 
According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179093/forked-repository-resolving-the-same-merge-conflicts-every-time-i-sync-with-up) you can run `git config rerere.enabled true` to record the resolution if for some reason the same exact conflict keeps happening

Comment: And yes, the folder will show up again if someone commits a new file to that folder. You could prevent that by adding the contents of that folder to `.gitignore` in your fork